# Javascript - arrow functions this in event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ES6, and can't quite get this to work:

`$(this)` returns undefined on click?

```
dom.videoLinks.click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log($(this));
            var self = $(this),
                url = self.attr(configuration.attribute);

            eventHandlers.showVideo(url);

            // Deactivate any active video thumbs
            dom.videoLinks.filter('.video-selected').removeClass('video-selected');

            // Activate selected video thumb
            self.addClass('video-selected');
        });
```

However if I change it so not be an *arrow function* like so, it works as expected?:

```
dom.videoLinks.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this);
            console.log($(this));
            var self = e.this,
                url = self.attr(configuration.attribute);

            eventHandlers.showVideo(url);

            // Deactivate any active video thumbs
            dom.videoLinks.filter('.video-selected').removeClass('video-selected');

            // Activate selected video thumb
            self.addClass('video-selected');
        });
```

So how would I go about it if I use an *arrow function* in the callback?

Answer (score 40):

With *arrow function* as a callback, instead of using `this` to get the element to which the handler is bound, you should use `event.currentTarget`.
Value of `this` inside an arrow function is determined by where the arrow function is *defined*, not where it is *used*.
So from now on,  keep in mind that
`event.currentTarget` **always refers to the** `DOM` **element whose EventListeners are currently being processed.**

---

### .currentTarget vs .target

Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` because of *event bubbling/capturing*:

- `event.currentTarget`- is the element that has the event listener attached to.
- `event.target`- is the element that triggered the event.

**[From the documentation:](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html)**

> `currentTarget` of type `EventTarget`, readonly Used to indicate the
>   `EventTarget` whose `EventListeners` are currently being processed. This
>   is particularly useful during *capturing* and *bubbling*.

**Check** the basic example in the **below snippet**

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "this: " + this.id +
    "<br> currentTarget: " + e.currentTarget.id +
    "<br>target: " + e.target.id;
});

$('#parent').on('click', function(e) {

  $('#jQmsg').html("*jQuery<br>this: " + $(this).prop('id')
                   + "<br>currenTarget: " + $(e.currentTarget).prop('id') 
                   + "<br>target: " + $(e.target).prop('id'));
});

$('#parent').on('click', e => $('#arrmsg').html('*Arrow function <br> currentTarget: ' + e.currentTarget.id));
```

```css
#parent {background-color:red; width:250px; height:220px;}
#child {background-color:yellow;height:120px;width:120px;margin:0 auto;}
#grand-child {background-color:blue;height:50px;width:50px;margin:0 auto;}
#msg, #jQmsg, #arrmsg {font-size:16px;font-weight:600;background-color:#eee;font-family:sans-serif;color:navy;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="parent">Parent-(attached event handler)<br><br>
    <div id="child"> Child<br><br>
      <p id="grand-child">Grand Child</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="msg"></div><br>
  <div id="jQmsg"></div><br>
  <div id="arrmsg"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You wouldn't.

Changing the value of `this` is the primary point of using an arrow function.

If you don't want to do that then an arrow function is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$(event.target)` instead of `$(this)` even inside of an arrow function. Arrow functions are preserving `this` of the scope where they were defined. In your case it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

> arrow functions and this selector?

Arrow functions retain `this` from enclosing context.
Eg.

```
obj.method = function(){
    console.log(this);
    $('a').click(e=>{
            console.log(this);
    })
};
obj.method(); // logs obj
$('a').click(); // logs obj
```

> So how would I go about it if I use an arrow function in the callback?

You already can - to access event target you can use something like  `$(e.target)`, but beware of bubbling. So I recommend to use normal functions instead as callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

The handling of `this` is also different in arrow functions compared to regular functions.

In short, with arrow functions, there is no binding of this.

In regular functions, the `this` keyword represents the object called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button, or whatever.

In arrow functions, the `this` keyword always represents the object that defined the arrow function.

To get the object called the arrow function, you must use `event.currentTarget` instead of `this`.

You defined `event` as the parameter `e` in your case.