# Scope of this in click handler ECMA script 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

As scope of `this` becomes available in `ES6` arrow functions.

but here is a case in which I am unable to access `this` in the arrow function while it is working with normal anonymous function

Example

**Sample 1**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.principal').click(() => {
        alert($(this).parent().html()); // 'this' is undefined here
    });
})
```

**Sample 2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.principal').click(function() {
        alert($(this).parent().html()); // 'this' is available here
    });
})
```

Comment: This is an classic question see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915875/javascript-arrow-functions-this-in-event-handler you will get the answer instead of this use e.target to get element required

Comment: @VinodLouis `event.currentTarget` is almost always better.

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes right currentTarget is safe to use i agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that jQuery explicitly binds the `this` object in your click handler to the element on which the event was captured. The only way to get that context is by using a standard function, since indeed an arrow function ignores this binding.

So you need to either:

- stick with a standard function for the callback, or
- Use the `currentTarget` property of the event object argument that jQuery passes to the callback

The latter would look like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.principal').click((e) => {
        console.log($(e.currentTarget).parent().html());
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button class="principal">Click me</button></div>
```

Outputs:

```
<button class="principal">Click me</button>
```

Comment: _"binds the context"_ should be "binds `this`".

Comment: Is that really so, JQuery doesn't work with arrow functions the way you'd typically expect? Very curious to see some detail on that somewhere, would like to run some tests to understand it fully.

Comment: @TimConsolazio, jQuery will bind the `this` object to the callback, but arrow functions are by design immune to that -- which is nothing jQuery can influence. You can read about the arrow function's behaviour in this respect on [MDN "No binding of this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this), in [this blog](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/) and ["Can you bind arrow functions?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions).

Comment: I understand arrow functions, I've been using them for quite some time. I misunderstood what you were getting at, but see now that your intent was to bind to the calling object; I typically avoid doing that in favor of binding to the closure that contains the handler, which is why typically I would prefer arrow functions. If however you were choosing to bind to the calling object, then I can see why you might not get the intended result from my answer.

Comment: @TimConsolazio, from the Asker's code it looked like they wanted to have the jQuery behaviour, where `this` is set to the element that was selected with the jQuery selector. In that respect it makes little sense to try to set `this` already to that element before calling the `click` method on the $ selector. Another hint is that `$(document).ready` is typically called outside of any function, but at the top level of a script. Putting it in any other place is unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.principal').click(() => {
        alert($(this).parent().html()); // 'this' is undefined here
    });
})
```

Since you are using arrow function, the `this` object here will belong to the context Outer function which is the `$(document).ready` and it is thus to the entire DOM element as you can see in the below snippet and not the clicked element.

In the second case

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.principal').click(function() {
        alert($(this).parent().html()); // 'this' is available here
    });
})
```

`this` refers to the context of the `click` function and thus it returns DOM element which is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.principal').click(() => {
            console.log(this); 
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="principal">Click</button>
```

Comment: _"this refers to the context of the click function and thus it returns DOM element"_  Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @zeroflagL I meant that it refer refer to the element on which the event was captured. Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Change the outer function to an arrow function too.

```
$( document ).ready ( ( ) => {
    $( '.principal' ).click ( ( ) => {
        alert ( $( this ).parent().html() ); 
    } );
} );
```

You can also try (added this option based on comment):

```
$( document ).ready ( function {
    $( '.principal' ).click ( ( ) => {
        alert ( $( this ).parent().html() ); 
    } );
}.bind ( this ) );
```

Comment: It is still `undefined`

Comment: Hmm I just tried it in a little naive example. I see a definition (albeit I am not using jquery). I have another option, I'll post as part of the answer.

Comment: plus 1 for using bind

Comment: Yeah it's not ES6 pure but the explicitness of "bind" to me was always useful.

Comment: You can't bind to arrow function. Please check this SO for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions

Comment: But what is `this` in this solution? Certainly not the `.principal` element, and so the `.parent()` method will fail.

Comment: Bartek, that was a typo, I just put the bind in the wrong place (notice I did change back to the "function", I just hadn't had my coffee yet). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Trincot, I wouldn't expect it to be the parent element. If you wanted access to that I think you'd be better off passing it in from the calling event. My assumption here is that "this" would be the object containing the handler.

Comment: `$(document).ready` is hardly ever called from within an object, but typically from the top level of a script. Also, the object desired to have as `this` is being *selected* with the jQuery selector (`.principal`), so it is only there that it becomes known.

Comment: I understand that as well...?

Answer (score 0):

In arrow function `this` has its original meaning from the enclosing context. In the first example `this` inside `ready` callback points to `document` and as a result `this` inside arrow function passed as click handler also points to `document`.
In the second example with normal function as click handler `this` is internally binded by jQuery to the element on which `click` method was called. Arrow function doesn't bind `this` argument but uses enclosing context - that's why `this` can't be binded as in cacse of normal function.

In your examples you don't need to access outer context inside click handler so you shouldn't use arrow function in such case, use normal function.